# Prove the matrix $x^2-4x+7$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cayley-hamilton

> Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2&3\\ -1&5\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$f(x) =x^2-4x+7$$ Show that $f(A)=O.$ Use this result to find $A^5$.

Solution:

$$f(A)=A^2-4A+7I\\=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 3 \\
        -1 & 2 \\
       \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 3 \\
        -1 & 2 \\
       \end{bmatrix}-4\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 3 \\
        -1 & 2 \\
       \end{bmatrix}+7\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
       \end{bmatrix}\\=\begin{bmatrix}
        4-3 & 6+6 \\
        -2-2 & -3+4 \\
       \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
        8 & 12 \\
        -4 & 8 \\
       \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
        7 & 0 \\
        0 & 7\\
       \end{bmatrix}\\=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 \\
       \end{bmatrix}$$

How to find $A^5$ ?

Comment: What is the $(2,2)$ entry? $5$? $2$? Make up your mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $$A^2 -4A +7I =O $$ $$\Rightarrow A^2 =4A-7I $$ $$\Rightarrow A^3=A^2 (A) =(4A-7I)A = 4A^2-7A = 4(4A-7I)-7A = 9A -28I $$ $$\Rightarrow A^5=A^3 (A^2) = A^3 (4A-7I) = (9A-28I)(4A-7I) = 36A^2 -175A +196I =36 (4A-7I)-175A+196I = -31A -56 I $$

Just repeatedly use the same formula while multiplying $A^2$ with $A$ continuously. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please explain how you got = 4(4A-7I)-7A. Rest i understood.

Comment: @bappy Observe that $A^2 =4A-7I$

Comment: @ stud_iisc  does he plugged the value of $$= A^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Use polynomial division to write:

$$x^5=(x^2-4x+7)q(x)+r(x)$$ where $\deg r(x)<2$.

Then substitute $x=A$.

Comment: if it is a second degree polynomial then this should be the characteristic polynomial but it isn't? why ? just a question

Comment: If what is a second degree polynomial?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Can you use said polynomial (Or a polynomial you can calculate from it) in order to find $A^5$ in terms of $A^4$ and $A^3$?

Answer (score 0):

Another, more advanced and abstract, way of looking at this is to observe that $\Bbb Z[A]\cong\Bbb Z[T]/(T^2-4T+7)$. To find what matrix goes to $T^5$, you just do Euclidean division on $T^5$, with the divisor $T^2-4T+7$. The remainder is your answer.